# What is default value of RAM cell for ARMs?

Tags: arm, ram

What is the default value of a RAM cell for ARM Cortex M0 (Nordic nrf51) after power reset? 
I guess that the answer is - undefined, but i am not sure.

Comment: At the hardware level, assuming the nrf51 has normal SRAM and not something wacky, then yes, the power-on state is probably relatively random (assuming also that it's been powered off for long enough to ignore retention effects). That's really an electronics question, though, and either way it's got nothing at all to do with the CPU core, thus no particular relevance to ARM.

Comment: ram is outside and attached to the arm core, cell library/foundry specific and a chip vendor thing not an ARM thing.  Its possible they have some bist or other logic in there, but that doesnt mean it runs on a normal boot (might only be for production testing).  I doubt the ARM logic messes with the ram it is associated with (L1 cache if any)  What happens when you boot and dump the ram before you write it?  You should always write memory before you read it, should never assume.

Comment: ARM makes cores. They lease/sell the IP as source code. You compile it to your foundry's cell library. If you have an L1 cache then you have a direct sram interface, there may be some others. Beyond that there are AHB/AMBA/AXI busses and what is beyond that is other IP either purchased or created by the chip vendor. The address space including how much ram and where it is part of that chip design, so ARM doesnt really know where your system ram is if they were going to have logic and burn a lot of time initializing it. But since the rule is never read ram you didnt write,why would they bother?

Comment: Funnily enough, [from today's HNQs](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248950/sram-isnt-blank-on-powerup-is-this-normal)...